# long long division with 32-bits memory

Tags: algorithm, memory, long-integer

I am currently working on a framework which transforms C to VHDL and I am getting stuck on the implementation of the long long division. Indeed, my framework is only able to work on 32-bits variable, so parsing a C long long variable will result into 2 VHDL variables, one containing the most significant part, one containing the least significant part. So to sum up, from this :

```
long long a = 1LL;
```

The VHDL which will be generated will be something like :

```
var30 <= 00000000000000000000000000000000;
var31 <= 00000000000000000000000000000001;
```

Now my problem is : how can I divide 2 long long parameters (in VHDL), since they are splitted in 2 variables ? I had no problem for the addition/substraction, since I can work on the most (resp. least) significant part independently (just a carry to propagate), but I really don't see how I could perform a division, since with this kind of operation, the least and the most significant part are really bound together... If someone has an idea, it would be much appreciated

PS : I have the same problem for the multiplication

EDIT : I both work on signed/unsigned variables and the result should be a 64-bit variable

Comment: Are your inputs signed or unsigned ?

Comment: They can be both signed or unsigned

Comment: Do you just want a 64 bit result or do you want the full 128 bit result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For both the multiplication and the division problem you can break the problem down like this: consider that each 64 bit value, x can be expressed as `k*x.hi+x.lo` where x.hi is the upper 32 bits, x.lo is the lower 32 bits, and k = 2^32. So for multiplication:

```
a*b = (a.hi*k+a.lo)*(b.hi*k+b.lo)
    = a.hi*b.hi*k*k + (a.hi*b.lo + a.lo*b.hi)*k + a.lo*b.lo
```

If you just want a 64 bit result then the first term disappears and you get:

```
a*b = (a.hi*b.lo + a.lo*b.hi)*k + a.lo*b.lo
```

Remember that in general multiplication doubles the number of bits, so each 32 bit x 32 bit multiply in the above expressions will generate a 64 bit term. In some cases you only want the low 32 bits (first two terms in above expression) but for the last term you need both the low and high 32 bits.

Comment: The problem with the division is that the expression you get cannot be simplified... So while I see how it can help for the multiplication, I don't for the division...

Comment: Think about how you learned to do long division by hand in elementary school and apply the same principles.

Comment: Sorry to disturb agian, I got your point on the division and made it work. However, for the multiplication, I'm a bit worried with this line : `a*b = (a.hi*b.lo + a.lo*b.hi)*k + a.lo*b.lo` . The problem is that `(a.hi*b.lo + a.lo*b.hi)` will generate a 64-bit value, and then we multiply it by k, which is not possible in my case since I can only multiply 32bit terms. Maybe it was the point of your last paragraph, but I must admit I did not really understand. Thanks, and sorry for disturbing.

Comment: For those terms you only need to generate the low 32 bits of the result since the high 32 bits will get shifted out of the 64 bit result, i.e. the low 32 bits get added to the high 32 bits of the result and the high 32 bits are not needed. I covered this in the answer above but maybe it wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Oh OK, so I just have to take the least significant part of `a.hi*b.lo + a.lo*b.hi`. Thank you very much, I'll mark your answer as best and accepted answer.